# MaterialDesginInXamlToolkit - Vertically align ListViewItem content

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, material-design-in-xaml

Using the default styling for everything, I can't get the heart icon to be vertically centered in this listview.
To reproduce the problem just create a super simple brand new WPF app and [add MaterialDesginInXamlToolkit `ResourceDictionary`s to App.xaml](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Super-Quick-Start), then add the following code:

> MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
    FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFont}"
    TextElement.FontSize="13"
    TextElement.FontWeight="Regular"
    TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
    TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"
    TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListView
        x:Name="listview"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
        VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Path
                                Width="{Binding Height, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                Height="12"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Fill="Red"
                                Stretch="Uniform"
                                Stroke="White"
                                StrokeThickness="1"
                                Visibility="{Binding IsLoved, ConverterParameter=True, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
                                <Path.Data>
                                    <PathGeometry Figures="M12 21.35l-1.45-1.32C5.4 15.36 2 12.28 2 8.5 2 5.42 4.42 3 7.5 3c1.74 0 3.41.81 4.5 2.09C13.09 3.81 14.76 3 16.5 3 19.58 3 22 5.42 22 8.5c0 3.78-3.4 6.86-8.55 11.54L12 21.35z" />
                                </Path.Data>
                            </Path>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="330" Header="Title">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

> MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            var items = new List<Item>();
            items.Add(new Item { IsLoved = true, Title = "This is a test" });
            items.Add(new Item { IsLoved = false, Title = "This is a test" });
            items.Add(new Item { IsLoved = true, Title = "This is a test" });
            items.Add(new Item { IsLoved = false, Title = "This is a test" });
            items.Add(new Item { IsLoved = true, Title = "This is a test" });

            this.listview.ItemsSource = items;
        }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public bool IsLoved { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
    public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool isVisible;

            try
            {
                isVisible = System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);
            }
            catch
            {
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            }

            var falseVisibility = parameter == null
                ? Visibility.Collapsed
                : Visibility.Hidden;

            return isVisible
                ? Visibility.Visible
                : falseVisibility;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Material Design's default ListViewItem style leaves  ListViewItem.VerticalContentAlignment unchanged from its default value of Top, instead of using the value set by the parent ListView. We can fix that like so:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignGridViewItem}">
        <Setter 
            Property="VerticalContentAlignment" 
            Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" 
            />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Make it `Stretch` instead of `Center` if you have items that need to fill the row vertically (e.g. borders, colored backgrounds). In that case, you'll have to explicitly set `VerticalAlignment="Center"` in all the templates, as you're now doing with the Path.

`MaterialDesignGridViewItem` is a style [defined here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ListView.xaml#L141).

On [line 155](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ListView.xaml#L155) we find the VerticalContentAlignment of the GridViewRowPresenter which presents the row content. It has a TemplateBinding which uses the VerticalContentAlignment defined for the ListViewItem. That Style has no Setter for that property, so it will just use the default value of [Control.VerticalContentAlignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control.verticalcontentalignment?view=netframework-4.8), which is `VerticalAlignment.Top`. `default(VerticalAlignment)` happens to be `Top`.

```
    <GridViewRowPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
```

Comment: yes, but that way you break up `MaterialDesginInXamlToolkit`'s styling system

Comment: I wonder why this is not the default behavior, as it much more common for a user to need it this way

Comment: What's irritating is that the default style doesn't grab the value set by the parent ListView, the way the WPF default works -- silly of me to forget that. See latest update.

Comment: I tried, in fact before asking here I checked the source style's xaml too, noticed it, and just thought it was me thinking the wrong way. Meh

Comment: Ok, just checked MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listview?view=netframework-4.8#properties), it says: `Do not use the HorizontalContentAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment properties for ListView content that is displayed by using a GridView. To specify the alignment of content in a column of a GridView, define a CellTemplate.`

Comment: Whoops, I tested it wrong. It does ignore that. Low IQ day, sorry. ListBox seems to use it though, and HorizontalContentAlignment definitely works that way on ListBox.

Comment: we live in a strange world :|