# MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit - Stretch ListView to full width

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, material-design

I am trying to stretch my `ListView.ItemTemplate` to the full width of the `ListView`. But since I'm using MaterialDesginInXamlToolkit, my styles break when I try.

Please can  someone help me to make my `ItemTemplate` full width and not lose style from MaterialDesginInXamlToolkit?

```
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style 
            TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter 
                Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I also found a similar solution here, but it doesn't work [MaterialDesginInXamlToolkit - Vertically align ListViewItem content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57679488/materialdesgininxamltoolkit-vertically-align-listviewitem-content)
Or rather, it breaks the entire ListView for me.
Was:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BoUh.png)
It became:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUZ43.png)
My ListView now looks like this:

```
            <ListView
                Name="ProductsListView">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border
                            Background="#ffff"
                            CornerRadius="5"
                            BorderThickness="1" 
                            BorderBrush="Bisque">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding description}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding price}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding discount}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding tags}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```